# Some means and sequence limit

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> If two sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ satisfy $a_0=a,b_0=b(a>0,b>0)$, and
>   $$\begin{cases}
>     a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\\
>     b_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{a_n^2+b_n^2}{2}}.
>   \end{cases}(n=0,1,2,\ldots)$$
>   Find the limit of $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$.

How about $$\begin{cases}
    a_{n+1}=\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}\\
    b_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{a_n^2+b_n^2}{2}}.
  \end{cases}(n=0,1,2,\ldots)$$

As we know, the [Arithmetic-Geometric Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) is, if two sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ satisfy $a_0=a,b_0=b(a>0,b>0)$, and
    $$a_ {n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}2,\qquad b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_nb_n}.$$
Let $\mathrm{AGM}(a,b)$ be the limit of $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$,Then 
$$\int_ {0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}}dt=\frac{\pi}{2\mathrm{AGM}(a,b)}.$$

Comment: So... What do you want? Asking for various methods?

Comment: @Philip Find the limit of first two problems, which are different from AGM.

Comment: @YuriyS Find the limit of problem in yellow texts.

Comment: May be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1625413/269624, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1826992/269624

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2655876/269624

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you very much